# Errors were encountered while processing: freeradius

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

Ubuntu version: 13.10

I can't remove or repair freeradius from software center.
Please help me!!

Click remove:
Display:

```
Package operation failed
installArchives() failed: 
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 215535 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing freeradius ...
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/freeradius not found.
dpkg: error processing freeradius (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 100
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/freeradius not found.
dpkg: libfreeradius2: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 freeradius depends on libfreeradius2 (= 2.1.12+dfsg-1.2ubuntu5.1).

Removing libfreeradius2 ...
dpkg: freeradius-common: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 freeradius depends on freeradius-common; however:
  Package freeradius-common is to be removed.

Removing freeradius-common ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 freeradius
```

Comment: Will you please edit your question and remove html tags use this [help](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the script `/etc/init.d/freeradius` is not available in your installation. Since you want to remove the package anyway …

… open the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/freeradius.prerm` via

```
sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/info/freeradius.prerm
```

and replace

```
case "$1" in
  remove)
        if [ -x "`which invoke-rc.d 2>/dev/null`" ]; then
                invoke-rc.d freeradius stop
        else
                /etc/init.d/freeradius stop
        fi
```

with

```
case "$1" in
  remove)
        # if [ -x "`which invoke-rc.d 2>/dev/null`" ]; then
        #         invoke-rc.d freeradius stop
        # else
        #         /etc/init.d/freeradius stop
        # fi
```

Now remove the package again.